# How can I pipe output into another command?

Tags: bash

I have a script located at /usr/local/bin/gq which is returned by the command `whereis gq`, well almost.  What is actually returned is `gq: /usr/local/bin/gq`.  But the following gives me just the filepath (with some white space)

> whereis gq | cut -d ":" -f 2

What I’d like to do is be able to pipe that into cat, so I can see the contents.  However the old pipe isn’t working.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `cat` the contents of `gq`, then how about:

```
cat $(which gq)
```

The command `which gq` will result in /usr/local/bin/gq, and the `cat` command will act on that.